# Overloading for forward iterators

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, overloading, libc++

While looking at libc++ I've found two different ways of overloading a function when template arguments are forward iterators.

First way is using `std::iterator_traits::iterator_category`

```
template <class ForwardIter1, class ForwardIter2>
inline
bool
__some_function(ForwardIter1 first1, ForwardIter1 last1,
                ForwardIter2 first2, ForwardIter2 last2,
                std::forward_iterator_tag, std::forward_iterator_tag)
{
    // do stuff ...

    return true;
}


template <class InputIter1, class InputIter2>
inline
bool
__some_function(InputIter1 first1, InputIter1 last1,
                InputIter2 first2, InputIter2 last2,
                std::input_iterator_tag, std::input_iterator_tag)
{
    // do stuff ...

    return true;
}


template <class InputIter1, class InputIter2>
inline
bool
some_function(InputIter1 first1, InputIter1 last1,
              InputIter2 first2, InputIter2 last2)
{
    return __some_function(first1, last1, first2, last2,
                           typename std::iterator_traits<InputIter1>::iterator_category(),
                           typename std::iterator_traits<InputIter2>::iterator_category());
}
```

But I've also seen uses of `std::enable_if`

```
template <class ForwardIter1, class ForwardIter2>
inline
bool
some_function(ForwardIter1 first1, ForwardIter1 last1,
              ForwardIter2 first2, ForwardIter2 last2,
              typename std::enable_if<
                  __is_forward_iterator<ForwardIter1>::value &&
                  __is_forward_iterator<ForwardIter2>::value
              >::type* = 0)
{
    // do stuff ...

    return true;
}


template <class InputIter1, class InputIter2>
inline
bool
some_function(InputIter1 first1, InputIter1 last1,
              InputIter2 first2, InputIter2 last2,
              typename std::enable_if<
                  __is_exactly_input_iterator<InputIter1>::value &&
                  __is_exactly_input_iterator<InputIter2>::value
              >::type* = 0)
{
    // do stuff ...

    return true;
}
```

Which of these two are the "prefered" way of solving the problem or does that depend on the situation. In that case, when would one solution be better than the other?

Comment: if you're using C++17 or later, then `if constexpr` is a third (and potentially much less verbose) option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way would be to use `enable if` as a return type so there is no need to pass any extra parameters (with defaulted value) to function:

```
template <class ForwardIter1, class ForwardIter2>
typename std::enable_if
<
    __is_forward_iterator<ForwardIter1>::value
    &&
    __is_forward_iterator<ForwardIter2>::value
,   bool
>::type
some_function
(
    ForwardIter1 first1, ForwardIter1 last1
,   ForwardIter2 first2, ForwardIter2 last2
)
{
    // do stuff ...
    return(true);
}
```

Also identifiers with double underscore are reserved, but let's assume that `__is_forward_iterator` template is valid and exist somewhere.

Comment: Ah, this looks much better than both of my examples! And yes, the reason for the double underscore functions is because I copied the examples from code I found in libc++, but thanks for the warning.